# Laravel runs Async HTTP Requests in Sequence instead of Concurrently

Tags: php, laravel, http

**Does not work:** I am trying to run multiple HTTP requests concurrently using Laravel's HTTP facade.
Unfortunately, Laravel always executes them in sequence when I am using `Http::async()->get(...)`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Utils;

$promises = [
    Http::async()->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
    Http::async()->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
];
$combinedPromise = Utils::all($promises);
$results = $combinedPromise->wait();
```

**Works:** If I am using Laravel's pool API instead the requests are executed concurrently as expected:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;

$responses = Http::pool(fn(Pool $pool) => [
    $pool->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
    $pool->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
]);
```

**Works:** Also, using GuzzleHttp directly I am able to execute the requests concurrently:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Utils;

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://postman-echo.com'
]);
$promises = [
    $client->getAsync('/delay/3'),
    $client->getAsync('/delay/3'),
];
$combinedPromise = Utils::all($promises);
$results = $combinedPromise->wait();
```

**Versions used:** I tested it with `"laravel/framework": "9.47.0"` and `"laravel/framework": "10.14.1"` in combination with `PHP 8.2.1`.

**Question:** Does anyone know why my `Http::async()->get(...)` calls are not executed concurrently but in sequence?

Comment: Is `localhost:8000` perhaps something being run by `php -S`?

Comment: @Sammitch no, the server has multiple workers and is able to process requests concurrently. Otherwise, the GuzzleHttp and Laravel Pool API versions above would not work either but they actually run the requests concurrently while `Http::async()->get(...)` runs them sequentially.

Comment: @Sammitch I also updated the example and no longer user localhost but instead Postman's Echo Service. This also makes it easier to reproduce the problem as you can tell by the execution time that the GuzzleHttp and Laravel Pool API versions are executed concurrently and only need 3-4 sec while the `Http::async()->get(...)` version runs for 7-8 sec as the requests run sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @txyoji who pointed me to the correct Laravel code I was able to find a solution that works with Laravel 9 and 10:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Utils;

$client = Http::async();
$client = $client->setClient(new Client([
    'handler' => $client->buildHandlerStack(),
    'cookies' => true,
]));

$promises = [
    $client->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
    $client->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
];
$combinedPromise = Utils::all($promises);

$results = $combinedPromise->wait();
```

Since Laravel 9 `PendingRequest.buildClient()` no longer calls `PendingRequest.getReusableClient()` to reuse the same GuzzleHttp Client across async requests.

- Laravel 8: [`PendingRequest.buildClient()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L825)
- Laravel 9: [`PendingRequest.buildClient()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L1026)

The code above explicitly sets a GuzzleHttp Client that is then reused across the async requests.

Comment: I raised a PR for the Laravel Framework to fix it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/48546

Answer (score 0):

[Docs show using pool to accomplish this.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#concurrent-requests)

The [Http facade returns a Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Factory.html) object.

If [PendingRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L1040) async() is true, it [doesn't reuse the client](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L822C21-L822C32).
My guess is each call of the Http facade is providing a separate client object.

Use the same client and it should work.

```
$client = Http::async();
$promises = [
    $client->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
    $client->get('https://postman-echo.com/delay/3'),
];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for linking the `PendingRequest` code of Laravel 8! Unfortunately, when testing it with Laravel 10 your suggestion does not work and the requests are still executed in sequence instead of concurrently. Also, I noticed that the code changed a bit in [Laravel 9](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L1026) and does no longer call `requestsReusableClient()`. Maybe, this is what is causing the trouble?